# Launch image not working

Tags: trigger.io

I just subscribed to Go iterate plan to use Launch image in my app and I still see Trigger.io logo image while my app loads. What's going on? oh and yes I did change my App config and specified the launch image

Comment: James Brady from Trigger.io got in touch with me real quick and asked to change the backward slash in the image path to forward slash and that fixed the issue. Btw, I'm on Windows 7 machine. They need to fix this in their toolkit so that it chooses the right slash going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your build that your App Config had backslashes in the paths to your launchimage files - I think you'll find that if you replace those with forward slashes you should be OK.

I'll look into whether our Toolkit failed to give the right behaviour here - thanks for the heads-up!